# internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:883 throw err

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli, npm-install

I've ran into an issue running `npm start` (I've attached the screenshot of the error bellow) on my Angular project.

When I run the project using `ng serve`, everything is working fine.

I have tried several ways to fix this issue without success.

[image: Screenshot of the error]

This is my `package.json` file:

```json
{
  "name": "myapplication",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~11.0.6",
    "@angular/common": "~11.0.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.0.6",
    "@angular/core": "~11.0.6",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.0.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.0.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.0.6",
    "@angular/router": "~11.0.6",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1100.6",
    "@angular/cli": "~11.0.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.0.6",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.0.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide your package.json file

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After spending a lot of time on the issue, I finally found the solution.

I've uninstalled **"NodeJs"** completely, deleted **"NPM"** & **"NPM-Cache"** from:

```sh
C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming
```

and restarted the PC. Then I've re-installed everything.

---

If the issue remains, check your folder names.

In my case, the Angular project was inside a folder named **"Research & Development"**:

```sh
C:\Users\Asus\Documents\Research & Development\Video conference project\myapplication
```

I have removed the special character **"&"** and renamed the folder to **"Research-Development"**

After the rename, `npm start` executed without errors.

[image: Command line screenshot]

Comment: My folder name was R&D and that's created the problem.

Comment: Wow, in my case, it really was the ampersand (&) character creating the issue!

Answer (score 6):

the solution is:

Delete `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`, then run `$ npm install` again.

You can also try updating your version of node.

Check version with `$ node -v`, install with `$ sudo n stable`

Comment: have you tried deleting npm cache? -- delete the "NPM" and "Npm-cache" folder under "Roaming" folder.

Comment: Can you check the entry point in your package.json? Sometimes the path is incorrect or you can just reinstall the node dependencies using npm i.

Comment: "scripts": {
  "start": "ng serve"
} 

you should make this change in your package.json

Comment: package.json file updated with the question, @Apoorva Chikara

Comment: My bad just forgot to check it, just remove ng from the file and it will work.

Comment: "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",  <---- remove this line this is no command in angular
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },

Comment: If that works can you accept the answer as i have update it in the above solution

Comment: Yes @Apoorva Chikara

Comment: there might be a issue with env path. There might be an issue with the way npm,node or angular installed that is why this is causing an issue

Comment: above error is ignorable, I spent an hr. to figure out what could be the issue and then after spending a long time thought of ignoring this error and go ahead with ng serve --host 0.0.0.0, it simply ran my application with no error.

Answer (score 3):

Solution with `yarn`:

1. remove `/node_modules` and `yarn.lock` file.
2. reinstall `packages/file` using `yarn install` .

Answer (score 2):

I was receiving this error in my screenshot (...883 throw error). I tried deleting package-lock.json and node_modules, then npm i, with no luck. For me, the error was in my package.json file. I had `"seed": "node server/config/seeds.js"` in my scripts instead of `"seed": "node config/seeds.js"` (which, it didn't need to direct to server because it was already within the server directory, I think? Still learning.).

Just wanted to add what helped solve this error for me since I have yet to see any solutions that match mine. Shoutout to Enricop89 because I only looked in my package.json due to his "nodemon" comment above! [screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HsvY7.png)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was running the wrong file using `nodemon`. So for example I was running `nodemon server.js` which didn't exist.

I changed to the correct one, `nodemon src/server.js` and got it working

Answer (score 0):

Just this has happened to me with node.js and I have solved it by changing the way to execute the file, I mean that if I executed it with `npm start` I would execute it with `npm ./src/index.js` (for example), you can try and me you say if it worked for you

Answer (score 0):

In my case I just removed the following entry from the PATH system variable:

> C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm

It could be found like this too:

> %APPDATA%\npm

But I guess each case could be different.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalled "NodeJs" completely, deleted "NPM" & "NPM-Cache" from:

Check your architecture whether its 32 bit processor or 64 bit processor for downloading the node.js.
When reinstall the node.js, the issue is completely resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I was running the wrong file using nodemon. I changed package.json entry for dev which is starting the nodemon.

`"scripts": { "start": "node dist/app.js", "dev": "nodemon src/app.ts", "build": "tsc -p ."  }`

I changed to the correct one, and got it working
//wrong one: nodemon app.ts
//correct one: nodemon src/app.ts

Answer (score 0):

Just rename your file path without spaces. Spent hours on it. E.g.

```
Video conference project/myapplication
```

to

```
video-conference-project/myapplication
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. What worked for me is the below solution:

I've uninstalled "NodeJs", deleted "NPM" & "NPM-Cache" from:
C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming

I reinstalled NodeJS and also angular-cli again.
Also, Once you install the angular-cli, make sure the node-modules folder gets created in below location:
C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm

Answer (score 0):

the solution is:

- `npm cache clean --force`
- delete the `node_modules`
- delete `package-lock.json`
- `npm install`

Answer (score -2):

I changed & to nothing just extra & sign was added to my file name. I took it out and I closed the VSC and reopen again it works as it was before.