# Cannot launch React project

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I am trying to launch a React project for the first time, but I am running into an error I don't understand.

I made a new React project with `create-react-app testreact`. That's seems to work fine.

However, when I try to launch it with `npm start`, I get the following error:

```
'JavaScript\testreact\testreact\node_modules\.bin\' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:883
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Stijn Klijn\Desktop\react-scripts\bin\react-scripts.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

Does anyone know what this means? And why is it trying to access a folder on my desktop? (which doesn't exist)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Cannot find module - that always mean, that u haven't installed module like axios/redux/.... or other techs.

yarn install - to install all basic modules6 that are already on ur project
yarn add 'module name'- add module to the project|

If u dont have yarn, then use npm (same beer)

Comment: What is your Node version (`node -v`)? What is your `npm` version (`npm -v`)?

Comment: node version is v14.16.0 and npm version is 7.11.2

Comment: That's odd. Are you sure you haven't made any changes to the project and have followed [the instructions](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app#quick-overview)?

Comment: Yeah I'm sure. Do you know why it is looking for a file on my desktop - in a directory which doesn't exist - in the first place?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:883 throw err](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65653417/internal-modules-cjs-loader-js883-throw-err)

Comment: Yes that fixed it. Apparently you can't have an & in the path's name. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like `react-scripts` did not install correctly
In your `package.json` file, in the dependencies, do you see `react-scripts`? If you do, try to delete your `node_modules` folder and run `npm i` again. If not, try running `npm uninstall react-scripts` and then `npm install react-scripts`

Comment: Apparently you can't have an & in the path's name. Removing that fixed it.